# Alternate (also local) NuGet package sources

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm facing a problem with connection to the default NuGet source (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/). It's an issue independent from me and I can't mend it, it's some kind of network related problem.

- Does anyone know alternate source(s) I can use?
- There's a "..." button in source dialog - can I use some kind of HDD based package source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own nuget package source. The following article could be useful.

http://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't know it's so simple to use local packages. It helped me a lot.